# How do I execute a batch script on click of a button in NWJS app?

Tags: nwjs

I have to execute a batch script on click of a button and I dont know where to begin. The batch scripts will do various different tasks for my nwjs application.

```
<input type="button" onclick="BatchFunc()"></button>
```

```
function BatchFunc() {
    code here
}
```

I tried this in various ways but got no success

```
function OpenTest() {
    nw.Shell.openItem('test.txt');
}
```

[image]

[image]

I tried this and when i click on the input it just shows a loading icon for a second then doesnt do anything else.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function runBatchFile () {
                const path = require('path');
                const executable = path.join('SOURCE CODE' , 'BATCH' , 'file.bat');
                const executableAndArgs = executable + ' --force --whatever';
                runExecutable(executableAndArgs, function (chunk) {
                    console.log({ chunk });
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A different take on Jared's suggestion:

```js
const { promisify } = require('node:util');
const exec = promisify(require('node:child_process').exec);
const path = require('node:path');

async function runBatchFile (filePath) {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(filePath);
  return { stdout, stderr };
}

const { stdout, stderr }= await runBatchFile(path.resolve('.', 'file.bat'));
console.log('stdout', stdout);
console.log('stderr', stderr);
```

Comment: what does the "." do in the file path do?

Comment: why are these so different than the stuff in the NWJS documentation?

Comment: I still havent got either of the suggestions to work unfortunately.

Comment: i added 2 screen shots of my project. i need to launch text.bat  onclick of documents button. Thes screens show my folder layout to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function runExecutable (executableAndArgs, callback) {
  const exec = require('child_process').exec;
  const child = exec(executableAndArgs, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('Executable Error: ', error);
    }
  });
  // Return any text that was output to the console
  child.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback(chunk);
    }
  });
}
function runBatchFile () {
  const path = require('path');
  const executable = path.join('.', 'folder', 'file.bat');
  const executableAndArgs = executable + ' --force --whatever';
  runExecutable(executableAndArgs, function (chunk) {
    console.log({ chunk });
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="runExecutable"></button>
```

Comment: does the . in the path before folder make it go back a dir?

Comment: is all of that necessary seams like a lotttt

Comment: The path is to wherever your file is. Most of that is just console logs, if you do not care about the data being logged, you can remove it. Play with the code until you understand it.

Comment: Wrapping `child_process.exec` in `util.promisify` cleans up the code significantly. You also don't need `child.stdout.on()`, if you only care about the output when the command is complete.

Comment: i added 2 screen shots of my project. i need to launch text.bat  onclick of documents button. Thes screens show my folder layout to.